# when using local repositories, MOTD updates to not match apt-get -s upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, repository

I am using ubuntu 16.04.  I have created a local mirror using apt-mirror, and have successfully pointed my install at the local mirror, and I have run apt-get update.

When I run apt-get -s upgrade, both when looking at the normal repositories and the local mirror, I get shown 69 packages to install:

```
-------------------------------->8--------------------------8<--------
69 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 7 not to upgrade.
-------------------------------->8--------------------------8<--------
```

However, when I log in, when apt is configured to use the local mirror, the motd shows no packages to update:
    Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-122-generic x86_64)

```
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

If I swap back to the standard repositories, then the MOTD is correct.  I am leaving it 24 hours to allow the MOTD to update.

What is the cause of the difference?  Where does the motd get it's information from, and what can I do to get it to show the correct information?